# How to get the multiple answer in select tag

Tags: reactjs, antd, multiple-select

I am using select tag in react app and ant design for css.
How can i get the data of multiple select tag.
I want to fetch the data of the image from the dropdown and uses on change and submit event for it.
for one option i am getting the data at the form but i am not sure what to use for multiple tag.
I am using Select and Input tag from ant design.

Comment: your question in incomplete. You should have included the tool you are using and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have used and design for select tag and react not anything else @Infinity

Comment: what type of tools you want to know ??

Comment: I have tried to show the image on click event for only one option that is successfully done but for multiple option what should i do that i want to know should i create a function for the multiple option or something else,

Comment: by using select mode = "multiple" i am able to click the multiple image in the dropdown, but for the answer what should i do?? @Infinity

Comment: I meant, Are you using some package for `select` dropdown or its just the default multiple select? Please edit your question for more info.

Comment: thank you @Infinity